# laravel5: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

Tags: laravel-5, vps

I have a problem when deploy website build on laravel 5 into VPS server, but on local machine it work fine.

My page is http://easyway.vn/ current page display blank with error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

When I run

> php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0

I have a error

> [ErrorException]
>     chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

Server Info

> OS: Linux 2.6
>   Server version: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
>   PHP 5.4.41 (cli) (built: Jun  4 2015 13:27:02)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

Help me please!

Comment: check that your folder 'public' exists and all the assets are inlcuded in it.
and check the index.php file (also included in public directory) has the right path for the autoload.php and app.php

Answer (score 47):

it means that your Laravel Application Can't Find the public folder.

I got it to work by

changing :

```
chdir($this->laravel->publicPath());
```

in :

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php`

To :

```
chdir('/');
```

Comment: althought we have to change path in index.php to point to bootstrap & in server.php, we have have to change path to point to index.php

Comment: I use your solution, but I set - `base_path()./web`

Comment: be aware that the vendor folder get overwritten once you run composer update. This is not ultimate solution.

Comment: Worked for me perfectly

Comment: you can simply create an empty public folder, that will also work.

Answer (score 16):

Renaming public folder name causes this issue.

Touching files under vendor directory is something you may never do.

Here is a working alternative way which I have tested and using in my active project.

Create app/Console/Commands/Serve.php files and set the content to this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Process\PhpExecutableFinder;
use Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessUtils;

class Serve extends Command {
    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'serve';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Serve the application on the PHP development server';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function fire() {
        chdir('/');

        $host = $this->input->getOption('host');

        $port = $this->input->getOption('port');

        $base = ProcessUtils::escapeArgument($this->laravel->basePath());

        $binary = ProcessUtils::escapeArgument((new PhpExecutableFinder)->find(false));

        $this->info("Laravel development server started on http://{$host}:{$port}/");

        if (defined('HHVM_VERSION')) {
            if (version_compare(HHVM_VERSION, '3.8.0') >= 0) {
                passthru("{$binary} -m server -v Server.Type=proxygen -v Server.SourceRoot={$base}/ -v Server.IP={$host} -v Server.Port={$port} -v Server.DefaultDocument=server.php -v Server.ErrorDocument404=server.php");
            } else {
                throw new Exception("HHVM's built-in server requires HHVM >= 3.8.0.");
            }
        } else {
            passthru("{$binary} -S {$host}:{$port} {$base}/server.php");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command options.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions() {
        return [
            ['host', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The host address to serve the application on.', 'localhost'],

            ['port', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The port to serve the application on.', 8000],
        ];
    }
}
```

Update the app/Console/Kernel.php file with this content:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        // Commands\Inspire::class,
        Commands\Serve::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //  ->hourly();
    }
}
```

That's all!

Now run your serve command:

```
$ php artisan serve
```

Server started:

```
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/
```

Comment: If you are using Laravel 5.4, change the `fire()` method in the `app/Console/Commands/Serve.php` file to `handle()`.

Comment: And please, can somebody explain why this problem even occurred in the first place. I absolutely remember doing nothing wrong. This raises serious concerns on **stability**

Answer (score 9):

I know you asked this question a long time ago but for those who seek the easiest and efficient way to solve this problem:

This error means laravel can't find the public folder.You must add this piece of code in the **register** method of **Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
       return base_path('PATH TO PUBLIC FOLDER');
    });
}
```

**Example with public_html**

In your case,, the path for public HTML will be:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
       return base_path('public_html');
    });
}
```

This way Laravel knows where to look to find the public folder path.

Answer (score 5):

Change

> chdir(public_path());

To

> chdir('/');

From : ***vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php***

Comment: You must never edit the vendor. This is the last thing that you want to do. When a new package is installed or updated the vendor will be changed.

Answer (score 5):

just create an folder named `public` in you root directory. If you downloaded projects from GitHub or existing old projects.

Answer (score 4):

1. **Step one** In vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php

> ```
> `chdir($this->laravel->publicPath());`
> ```

```
change to
```

> `chdir('/');`

2.**Step two** Change these two paths in your_public_folder/index.php

> `require __DIR__.'/../your_app/bootstrap/autoload.php';`
>
> `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../your_app/bootstrap/app.php';`

3.**Step three** Change public path in your_app/server.php

```
    if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/../public_html/'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/../public_html/index.php';
```

> **Note**: Change these path according to your App's new folder structure.

Answer (score 3):

this error appears when you rename the `public` folder.

**Never** edit files in vendor folder. After *composer update* or *fresh install* you will lose your changes.

A better solution is to edit *bootstrap/app.php* and place this snippet before the return statement.

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path() . '/web';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

go to server.php in root folder and rename any `public` to `any name you have`

Answer (score 1):

Usually when this type of error occurs it means Laravel is Looking for a public folder and it cannot be found. This depends on how you have configured your application and using php artisan serve `--host=0.0.0.0` will not work in this case. The best way to handle this is to place you application in your server(htdocs) and access it in your url.

The vendor directory contains your Composer dependencies. Visit [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/structure#the-vendor-directory) for details. Never edit anything in vendor because it may cause problem when you do composer update.

Comment: This was very useful information to me. I had a missing public folder. Fixed by regenerating public files using `npm run dev` (laravel 5.4).

Answer (score 0):

remember when you run in production the path of public change to public_html so to run again in localhost  I changed into app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

this:

```
public function register()
    {
       $this->app->bind('path.public',function(){return'/public';});
    }
```

to this:

```
public function register()
    {
       // commented this line
    }
```

Also after changed .env enviroment and in server.php and index.php

Answer (score 0):

be sure if "public" folder exist or no

Comment: Although this could be the correct answer to the question, it helps when you explain why and how your answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might have overwritten the `public_path` method, maybe in `AppServiceProvider` or `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Never edit files in vendor folder. A simple solution is just create an folder named "public" in you root directory and copy into this folder an "index" of a project that works.

INDEX

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```