# I have a laravel5 project downloaded from the cpanel but it's not working

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I've added the project file to the htdocs file in my mac and exported the database , composer install is working fine , php artisan-migrate gives me an error of duplicated database and tables .. but when i run php artisan serve it gives me error and won't run on localhost:8000
Here is the error i get

```
[ErrorException]
chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)
```

Comment: Please don't use phrases like "Please help me ASAP" in your question.

Comment: !! .. Didn't know that it's prevented .. Thanks anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel5: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873773/laravel5-chdir-no-such-file-or-directory-errno-2)

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs because Laravel cannot find your public folder.

One solution, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873773/laravel5-chdir-no-such-file-or-directory-errno-2), is to change this line:

```
chdir($this->laravel->publicPath());
```

in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php` to:

```
chdir('/');
```

See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Empty your database and then run php artisan migrate. Then use

For serve error :

it means that your Laravel Application Can't Find the public folder.

Change

```
chdir($this->laravel->publicPath());
```

in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php To :

```
chdir('/');
```

Comment: php artisan migrate gives me new error now -_-  "[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'sessions' a  
  lready exists (SQL: create table `sessions` (`id` varchar(255) not null, `p  
  ayload` text not null, `last_activity` int not null, `user_id` int unsigned  
   null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci) " and another error  that i will post in the next comment

Comment: here is the other error  " [PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'sessions' a  
  lready exists  "

Comment: Can i contact you on private ?

Comment: Yes. you need to empty all table and then run migration

Comment: I did .. and got this error -_-   [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'justnew.settings' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `settings` where `settings`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

Comment: Please check if database 'justnew' has that name table 'settings'. Your connection config might be doing problem please check your config from config/database.php .

Comment: can i have your twitter account or any account to contact with you on private and send you couple of screenshots .. it would be very helpful

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100006738768037 contact me here