# Missing public folder in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.6

I received a project from my client. I tried to install it in my local machine using `php artisan serve` command and I found below error

[image]

After searching in Google I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873773/laravel5-chdir-no-such-file-or-directory-errno-2) question. Then I found that there is no public folder in my project directory.

[image]

Is there any specific reason to delete this **public** folder ? or it is left accidentally ?

I changed

`chdir($this->laravel->publicPath());`

in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php To :

```
chdir('/');
```

as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873773/laravel5-chdir-no-such-file-or-directory-errno-2) question. After that I am getting a blank white page while I am running my project using `php artisan serve`.

What is the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They probably tried setting up the app to run from the root directory, instead of public folder. Usually happens when a Laravel app is setup to run (incorrectly i might add) on shared hosting.

create a new public directory & move your js, css & index.php files back into it. Also check for any explicit paths that reference index.php from the root directory & update them so they point to the public dir instead. You'll also have to create a new htaccess file (or move the existing one from root) in your public dir .

Just compare with the dir structure of a clean laravel install and you'll be able to see what you're missing.

Answer (score 3):

Most new developers are using this method for hiding the public folder in real server due to lack of experience. I suggest you edit back the main folder to "public" from  '/'

Firstly, look at your `index.php` file and replace

```
$app = require_once 'bootstrap/app.php';
```

to `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

2) Change `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

3) Create a new public folder and put your **asset files** and **index.php** there.

You can try `php artisan config:clear` after those steps.

Don't forget the main purpose is getting back the **public** folder.