# laravel routing not working on ip address

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, dns, routes

i implement laravel on vps server that just have a ip address and have no domain.

its work and show the index file but routing is not working and show me 404 not found page.

this is my web.php file:

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/test' , function(){
    return 'this is test route';
});
```

and in the .env file set the ip:

```
APP_URL=http://178.63.245.92
```

and this is the ip address of my vps : http://178.63.245.92/

when i say : http://178.63.245.92/test
its say:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /test was not found on this server.
```

what is have to do.

thanks.

Comment: Are you using Apache as web server?

Comment: Try clearing your cache: `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: yes its an apache on centos 7

Comment: Have you set your vhost right?

Comment: @script47  i run php artisan cache:clear but its not solved the issue

Comment: @rkg  yes its configed by hosting provider.

Comment: @meti is the `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: @IlGala let me check it.

Comment: @IlGala yes its uncommented 'LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@IlGala Thank You for point the `my mod_rewrite` module,  my`mod_rewrite` module was Enable but i read  [here](https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-centos-7/) after you Enbale `my mod_rewrite` you have to allow Apache to read .htaccess files located under the /var/www/html directory.
i grant the access as the structures says on that page and its solved.

thanks every body.

Answer (score 1):

You can set route to desired ip address using this command

```
php artisan serve --host 178.63.245.92 --port 80
```

Comment: i serve it and its say :   ErrorException  : chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

Comment: this post could help you:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873773/laravel5-chdir-no-such-file-or-directory-errno-2

Comment: If the address is already in use, it will be because a child process is still alive. Once that process is found and killed, you will be able to reissue that command.

Comment: @Suvin94  thank you , i solve the issue and serve it again and its say :  "Failed to listen on 178.63.245.92:80 (reason: Address                   already in use) 
"

Comment: @Jim Grant if i restart the server is gonna be solved?

Comment: Yes, you have to kill the running service first @meti