# return error when run php artisan serve comand ([ErrorException] chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2))

Tags: php, laravel

One laravel project works fine on host. When I download project files and wants to run it on Xampp I have some problems.

At first `php artisan` command works fine. But when I want to run `php artisan serve` it returns Error:

> [ErrorException]
>
> chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

After that I tried to fix it and searched in stackoverflow questions and none of them can help me.

I tried `php artisan config:clear` command and it works fine. After that when I want to run `php artisan` returns another error that is:

> [Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException]

Laravel version: `"laravel/framework": "5.5.*"`

**Update**:

I know why return **NotFoundHttpException** error after config cache command. It's because `APP_URL` set to `http://localhost:8000`. Before that it's set to domain address that works on it(on host with this domain) fine.

I tested all answers in related question so please don't vote as duplicate because it's a little different with those.

Please help if you have had this problem in the past.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel5: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873773/laravel5-chdir-no-such-file-or-directory-errno-2) or https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/moving-files-to-other-directory-shows-chdir-no-such-file-or-directory-errno-2-error

Comment: @Rwd no. I test them. I update my question.