# Creating new laravel project and this error came up

Tags: laravel, exception, chdir

Creating new laravel project and this  error came up

[ErrorException]
chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

[image]

Comment: [ErrorException]
  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

Comment: Does this help: [laravel5: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873773/laravel5-chdir-no-such-file-or-directory-errno-2)

Answer (score 0):

it means that your Laravel Application Can't Find the public folder.

I got it to work by

changing :

```
chdir($this->laravel->publicPath());
```

In:

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php

To:

> chdir('/');

Comment: I got no laravel application yet to chage it !