# Can't php artisan serve: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ on line 21

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I run php artisan tinker

then my vs code become error

I do research an implementing

[laravel5: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873773/laravel5-chdir-no-such-file-or-directory-errno-2)

and I was do the required to change code, I was exited, caused my code can do composer update.

but when it start again, it still got the same error.

this is the error

```
[Thu Mar 24 06:18:27 2022] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): 
Failed opening required 
'/home/john/Documents/api4/api4/public/index.php' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
```

/home/john/Documents/api4/api4/server.php on line 21

```
this is on line 21 at server.php

if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
return false;
 }

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php' ;
```

this is the tinker

```
'alias' => [
    //
],
```

And about tinker, I still don't know how the functional of that code. I just want to make pop up and learn from page that I open to instruct me do that code.

Have you ever using that code? I mean : php artisan tinker?

hopefully you explain me in simple way and give direction from my problem.

thanks

Comment: Please include the actual code.

Comment: I would Also Suggest not using Laravel 5 the newest version is 9. Alot has changed both in code as well from a Security Standpoint.

Comment: Oke Sir, I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add vendors directory first by running the install command for the composer:

```
composer install
```

After that update your composer packs:

```
composer update
```

Comment: done, thank's Sir

Comment: before that, I create new file in vendor, then I run composer install